# JFrame GUI IntelliJ

Tags: java, user-interface, intellij-idea, netbeans

I have a question regarding how the JFrame works in IntelliJ.

I'm trying to create a simple GUI but I can't easily resize a button, or just move it to a diffrent place like in NetBeans, or re size the interface, etc. I don't know if Netbeans has a better way to desing GUI's or if I am missing something about the way IntelliJ works.

Comment: No, what you're missing is nothing to do with IDEs. You're missing how Swing lays out components. I suggest you take a Swing tutorial, particularly around layout managers

Comment: "Manual" or "null" layouts are not recommended as they don't take into consideration the many factors which effect their sizes - use the layout management system provided by Swing, that's reason it exists

Answer (score 0):

## Layout managers

You should nearly always be using a layout manager in Swing. You specify areas of the layout in which you want your controls (buttons, fields, etc.). The layout manager determines the exact pixel positioning.

See [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) by Oracle.

Java comes bundled with some very good layout managers. You can also choose from some interesting third-party layout managers.